# Create a topic or insert a new message Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Order topic where customers pushes a order messages. When order is completed by seller it should be changed to confirmed status. Shoud I creater a new topic as `accepted_orders` with information about seller and order? Like in relation tables. Or insert a new message to existing topic with extended information?

Comment: It depends on your data processing pipe and your application. What are you going to do with accepted orders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> insert a new message to existing topic with extended information?

Into the orders topic? Then you'd consume it again and need to filter out all each of the unfilled statuses. That'll work, but it'll obviously slow down the processing as you're now consuming two messages for every one order

Therefore, a new topic, or a new partition keyed by order status, would be recommended